# Artistic pre-teen hardcover about a girl who disobeys her family and ventures beyond a curtain with a door, to a land of trolls

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story, trolls

I picked up this book at the mall in the mid-late 90s, and it was a beautifully artistic storybook about a girl who took her life for granted/was bored, and decided to venture behind a curtain in her house (with a wooden door/way painted on it). There she encountered trolls (or similar), and heard of the evil troll Queen, who she eventually meets, and either escapes from/tricks/destroys, before venturing back to her world/home.

The illustrations were dark but extremely detailed, and will haunt me forever...